# How to bind a key to open the highlighted file with vim?

Tags: vim, tmux

If I highlighted a filename in the copy mode, how could I open that file with vim by a hotkey?

I'm imagining something like:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-o' send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "vim $(tmux paste-buffer)"
```

but that doesn't work, plus piping is redundant in this case.

I know there is [tmux-open](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-open) which should do similar thing, but it doesn't work for me somehow.

Environment: OSX 10.13.5, iTerm2 3.1.7, Tmux stable 2.7 built by homebrew

Comment: There is no "copy mode" in Vim, do you mean visual mode?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Here is the workflow I expected: 
1. In bash, search for the files I want, say `find . -name foo.php`
2. It prints "./aaa/bbb/foo.php". Now I enter the copy mode of tmux, and highlight "./aaa/bbb/foo.php".
3. Press Ctrl + o and have vim open the file for me, as if I run `vim ./aaa/bbb/foo.php`.

Does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

I normally have these settings in my vimrc

```
set hidden 
set path+=**
```

Then you can just press `gf` when you cursor is over a word. If you want to open it on a new window, press <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd> `gf`.  If you just use `gf` you can go back by pressing <kbd>Ctrl-6</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the tip. However, my question is more about tmux, not vim, as replied in the comment under the question above. Sorry for the confusion.